# How do you make a wpf text adornment modal?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

Following this [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2009/12/09/building-and-publishing-an-extension-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx) I was able to create an adornment that used a wpf user control as it's visual.  This works but the interaction with the user control is not what I expected, it just sits on top of the text editor and I can still make changes to the editor directly.  How do I make the user control modal so that it acts more like a form and requires input or is removed if you click somewhere else in the editor?

[image]

Comment: I don't think adorners are supposed to be modal, you would need to use the click event of the adorner to open a new form and make that modal.

Comment: So maybe modal is the wrong term.  I just want the form to get focus and keep it, just like the insert snippet form works.  When you invoke that form, it gets focus and accepts keyboard/mouse clicks, you can type and click within that form but if you click anywhere else on the editor it disappears

Comment: Right, the insert snippet isn't an adorner though... You are using the right term.